# RestAngular: put and customPUT are sending old object, not updated one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, restangular

When I call `put` or `customPUT` and check the request body in the browser, the original object is sent, not the updated one. I checked the RestAngular object with a `{{ object }}` and it **is** being updated.

Here is the **controller** (`APIUsers` is a RestAngular Service):

```
$scope.objects = {};
(function waitForNgInit(fnct) {
    $scope.$watch('userID', function(newVal) {
        if (newVal !== undefined) {
            fnct();
        }
    });
})(function retrieveUser() {
    $scope.objects.user = APIUsers.one($scope.userID).get().$object;
});

$scope.saveSettings = function() {
    $scope.objects.user.customPUT($scope.objects.user).then(function(resp) {
        $scope.errors = [];
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err.data);
        $scope.errors = err.data.errors;
    });
};
```

Here is the Jade (**HTML Template Code**):

```
div.user-settings.form-section(ng-controller="userSettingsFormController")
    {{ objects }}
    ul.error-box(ng-show="errors != undefined && errors.legnth != 0")
        li(ng-repeat="error in errors") {{ error.msg }}
    .form-group
        label(for="username") Username
        input(type="textfield" ng-model="objects.user.username")
    .form-group
        label(for="username") Email
        input(type="textfield" ng-model="objects.user.email")
    .form-group
        label(for="username") Profile Picture
        input(type="file" ng-model="objects.user.profilePicture")
    span.submit-button(ng-click="saveSettings()") Save Changes
```

Comment: do you have, `RestangularProvider.setDefaultHttpFields({cache: true});` set somewhere ?

Comment: @sinθ Check the answer. Sadly it is a known bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is an old and known Restangular bug, see it at https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/713

To make this work in the meanwhile is fixed (it seems that are working to fix it), you can use the code below:

```
$scope.submit = function submit() {
    Restangular
      .copy($scope.ledger)
      .save()
      .then(function () {
        growl.success(gettext('Updated successfully.'));
      });
  };
```

Comment: Restangular uses a cache much aggressively and will use cached data instead of modified one. That's why Restangular.copy() is needed

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I think you need to wait for the digest cycle to complete for the underlying restangular object to update.

Try wrapping your `put()` behind a `$timeout` call:

```
$timeout(function () {
  $scope.objects.user.customPUT($scope.objects.user).then(function(resp) {
    $scope.errors = [];
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err.data);
    $scope.errors = err.data.errors;
  });
});
```